# Creating a link to an id that refreshes the page

Tags: javascript, php

I am working on a project that uses javascript to make tabs.  It has 3 tabs.

Tab three has an id of tab3, what I need is a refresh button that will be on tab3 that will refresh the page. Problem I'm having is if you click on tab3 it will display tab3 data, but it does not change the url.  So the refresh button isn't working.

I tried an onclick javascript that reloads the page using location.reload() which reloads the page but not to the tab3.  So I put that on a link,

```
<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>#tab3" onclick="reloadPage();" >Refresh</a>
```

This will link to the correct location, the URL then has #tab3 at the end, then the Javascript runs and it reloads back to the url without the #tab3.

So I then tried this that I saw somewhere.

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="window.location = '<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>#tab3;'">Go</a>
```

Which links, but doesn't reload.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: URL with hash `#` on the current page tells to the browser to scroll to an HTML-element, not to reload.

Answer (score 2):

Try this-

```
<a href="#tab3" onclick="location.reload();" >Refresh</a>
```

Comment: This relaods the page.  So if you are on http://www.example.com/index.php/ you can click on tab3 which would load the content for tab3, but the URL stays at http://www.example.com/index.php/, if you click this link it will move the widnow to the tab3 id, so the url would then look like http://www.example.com/index.php/#tab3, then I guess the Javascript kicks in and the page reloads, but it doesn't use the new #tab3 url it reloads back to the index.php page.

Answer (score 0):

In head put,

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function goto(link) {
window.location = link
}
</script>
```

and do this to your button

```
<a onclick=goto("<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '#tab3'; ?>"); >GO </a>
```

if you want to refresh the page and aslo goto same place this code will work

```
<form method=post action="">
<input type=hidden name=value value="#tab3" />
<input type=submit value=GO />
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['value']))
{
header('Location: http://'. $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST] . $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI] . $_POST["value"]);
}

?>
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  When you go to say example.com/index.php which uses javascript to have tabs.  So when index.php loads it is on tab1.  Now you would click on tab3, which keeps the url the same but would switch to tab3.   Now on tab3 I need to put in a refresh button to refresh the page but stay on tab3.  With the above, it does link to the correct tab but it does not refresh the content.

Answer (score 0):

Using window.location is the solution, however if the current location is already the same as the new url that is assigned, then browser will not re-load the page. 
The only trick would be to make the new url look "new". This can be done by adding a random identifier as querystring parameter.
**In the form:**

```
http://hostname?<dynamic/random>#tab3
```

**Example:**

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="window.location = '<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>' + Date.now() + '#tab3;'">Go</a>
```

Comment: This does add the data at the end of the link but it doesn't link to the #tab3, I was thinking maybe using php to check the $_GET for the tab3, but I think this is adding an extra step that I don't need.

Comment: Clarification: 1.)moving from one tab to another is handled in JS. 2.) After moving to tab3 by means of javascript, if a button is pressed the content of tab3 needs to be refreshed.  If this is true, then in the page loading sequence there should be JS code that is acting on enabling the correct tab as the browser will only try to move the focus to the given #id. But the whole statemachine of the UI is owned by the JS part of the app, and it needs handle the incoming hash link.  Doing this in PHP is like duplicating the logic in two different places.  My answer covered only request initiation.

Comment: If you were to use any if the modem JS MVC frameworks,  handling of the hash id would be done via the concept of "routes" (E.g. backbone, ember, ...).